# Unable to read static json file data in the aurelia Project folder, Compiler Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, webpack, aurelia

I am using TypeScript as Compiler for Aurelia Project.Trying to load 
'.json static file which is under the Project Folder'

**I am getting the following error 404 status not found**. 
Tried to place json file at both inside and outside of SRC folder but unable to load the Json file.

If I miss any like setting up a configuration then please guide me. 
Here is Code and Json Data and error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you typically wouldn't fetch a static json like this unless you had a task in your webpack to copy the file to your dist folder.  the webpack dev server you are running with aurelia cli `au run` command doesn't know about the file unless you copy it or import the json somewhere.  typescript supports json import as of typescript 2.9 if you have `resolveJsonModule: true` in the tsconfig.json file.  that means you just need to `import json from '.\JsonRead.ts'.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, since the file is directly in the project you don't need HttpClient at all. Simply import the file directly.

```
import jsonRead from "./JsonRead.json";

export class App {
  message = 'Hello World';

  bind(){
    const json = JSON.stringify(jsonRead);
    console.log(json);
  }
}
```

Remember to enable **"resolveJsonModule": true** at tsconfig.json file for this to work.

If you want to use HttpClient, your json file needs to be inside **static** folder for webpack to pack it as public file.